# Cesium bind camera to model

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have put Cesium model

```
let modelMatrix = Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(
  Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
    longitude,
    latitude,
    altitude
  )
);

let model = this.viewer.scene.primitives.add(Model.fromGltf({
    url : URL,
    modelMatrix : modelMatrix,
    minimumPixelSize : 1,
    maximumScale : 1
}));
```

And im  going to change its position (model will fly)
And I would like to know is there a way to bind camera to this model.
Something like this:

```
let camera = this.viewer.camera.bindToModel(model, OPTIONS);
```

So when model will change its position - camera will also move.
Thanks

Comment: Would something like [the Multipart CZML Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Multi-part%20CZML.html) be similar to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why my

```
viewer.trackedEntity = myModel;
```

did not focus camera on model, is that i used

```
let myModel = viewer.scene.primitives.add(MODEL);
viewer.trackedEntity = myModel;
```

to add model on scence and focus on it. 
When i changed to

```
let myModel = viewer.entities.add(MODEL_DESC);
viewer.trackedEntity = myModel;
```

My camera focused on model and follow it on position change, as i need.
Thanks [emackey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836708/emackey) for useful example [Multipart CZML Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Multi-part%20CZML.html) that helped to solve my task